# i want to know where to put my java code in opendaylight project , load balancing routing

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

i am new to opendaylight i have installed mininet and connected to the controller successfully. I want to implement dynamic load balancing on the controller i have the java code with me the problem is I donot know where to put it

```
    **
     * @file
     LbRoutingImplementation.java
     *
*
* @brief
Implementation of a routing engine using
* lb_routing. Implementation of lb_routing
come from Jung2 library
*
*/
package org.opendaylight.controller.routing.lb_routing_implementation.internal;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core.Bandwidth;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core.ConstructionException;
import org.opendayli
ght.controller.sal.core.Edge;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core.Node;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core.NodeConnector;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core.Path;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.core.Property;
import org.op
endaylight.controller.sal.core.UpdateType;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.reader.IReadService;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.routing.IListenRoutingUpdates;
import org.opendaylight.controller.sal.routing.IRouting;
import org.opendaylight.co
ntroller.sal.topology.TopoEdgeUpdate;
import org.opendaylight.controller.switchmanager.ISwitchManager;
import org.opendaylight.controller.topologymanager.ITopologyManager;
import org.opendaylight.controller.topologymanager.ITopologyManagerAware;
import org
.opendaylight.controller.statisticsmanager.internal.StatisticsManager;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.shortestpath.DijkstraShortestPath;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.SparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.
util.EdgeType;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concu
rrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;
public class LbRoutingImp
lementation implements IRouting, ITopologyManagerAware {
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory
.getLogger(LbRoutingImplementation.class);
private ConcurrentMap<Short, Graph<Node, Edge>> topologyBWAware;
private ConcurrentMap<Sho
rt, DijkstraShortestPath<Node, Edge>> sptBWAware;
DijkstraShortestPath<Node, Edge> mtp; // Max Throughput Path
private Set<IListenRoutingUpdates> routingAware;
private ISwitchManager switchManager;
30
private ITopologyManager topologyManager;
private IReadService readService;
private static final long DEFAULT_LINK_SPEED = Bandwidth.BW1Gbps;
private StatisticsManager statMgr;
private Timer lbRoutingTimer;
private TimerTask lbRoutingTimerTask;
public void setListenR
outingUpdates(IListenRoutingUpdates i) {
if (this.routingAware == null) {
this.routingAware = new HashSet<IListenRoutingUpdates>();
}
if (this.routingAware != null) {
log.debug("Adding routingAware listener: 
{}", i);
this.routingAware.add(i);
}
}
public void unsetListenRoutingUpdates(IListenRoutingUpdates i) {
if (this.routingAware == null) {
return;
}
log.debug("Removing routingAware listener");
this.routingAware.remove(i);
if (this.routingAware.isEmpty()) {
// We don't have any listener lets dereference
this.routingAware = null;
}
}
@Override
public synchronized void initMaxThroughput(
final Map<Edge, Number> EdgeWeightMap) {
if (mtp != null) {
log.error("Max Throughput Dijkstra is already enabled!");
return;
}
Transformer<Edge, ? extends Number> mtTransformer = null;
i
f (EdgeWeightMap == null) {
mtTransformer = new Transformer<Edge, Double>() {
public Double transform(Edge e) {
if (switchManager == null) {
log.error("switchManager is null");
return (double) 
-
1;
}
NodeConnector srcNC = e.getTailNodeConnector();
NodeConnector dstNC = e.getHeadNodeConnector();
if ((srcNC == null) || (dstNC == null)) {
log.error("srcNC:{} or dstNC:{} is null", srcNC, dstNC);
return (double) 
-
1;
}
Bandwidth bwSrc = (Bandwidth) switchManager
.getNodeConnecto
rProp(srcNC,
Bandwidth.BandwidthPropName);
Bandwidth bwDst = (Bandwidth) switchManager
.getNodeConnectorProp(dstNC,
Bandwidth.BandwidthP
ropName);
34
// If the src and dst vertex don't have incoming or
// outgoing links we can get ride of them
if (topo.containsVertex(src.getNode())
&& topo.inDegree(src.getNode()) == 0
&
& topo.outDegree(src.getNode()) == 0) {
log.debug("Removing vertex {}", src);
topo.removeVertex(src.getNode());
}
if (topo.containsVertex(dst.getNode())
&& top
o.inDegree(dst.getNode()) == 0
&& topo.outDegree(dst.getNode()) == 0) {
log.debug("Removing vertex {}", dst);
topo.removeVertex(dst.getNode());
}
}
spt.
reset();
if (bw.equals(baseBW)) {
clearMaxThroughput();
}
} else {
log.error("Cannot find topology for BW {} this is unexpected!", bw);
}
return edgePresentInGraph;
}
priv
ate boolean edgeUpdate(Edge e, UpdateType type, Set<Property> props) {
String srcType = null;
String dstType = null;
if (e == null || type == null) {
log.error("Edge or Update type are null!");
return false;
} else {
srcType = e.getTailNodeConnector().getType();
dstType = e.getHeadNodeConnector().getType();
if (srcType.equals(NodeConnector.NodeConnectorIDType.PRODUCTION)) {
log.debug("Skip updates f
or {}", e);
return false;
}
if (dstType.equals(NodeConnector.NodeConnectorIDType.PRODUCTION)) {
log.debug("Skip updates for {}", e);
return false;
}
}
Ban
dwidth bw = new Bandwidth(0);
boolean newEdge = false;
if (props != null)
props.remove(bw);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
log.debug("edgeUpdate: {} bw: {}", e, bw.getValue());
}
35
Short baseBW = S
hort.valueOf((short) 0);
boolean add = (type == UpdateType.ADDED) ? true : false;
// Update base topo
newEdge = !updateTopo(e, baseBW, add);
if (newEdge == true) {
if (bw.getValue() != baseBW) {
/
/ Update BW topo
updateTopo(e, (short) bw.getValue(), add);
}
}
return newEdge;
}
@Override
public void edgeUpdate(List<TopoEdgeUpdate> topoedgeupdateList) {
boolean callListeners = false;
for (int i = 0; i < topoedgeupdateList.size(); i++) {
Edge e = topoedgeupdateList.get(i).getEdge();
Set<Property> p = topoedgeupdateList.get(i).getProperty();
UpdateType type = topoedgeupdateList.get(i).getUpdateTy
pe();
if ((edgeUpdate(e, type, p)) && (!callListeners)) {
callListeners = true;
}
}
if ((callListeners) && (this.routingAware != null)) {
/*Map<Edge, Number> edgeWeightMap = new
Map<Edge,
Number >();
Bandwidth bw = new Bandwidth(0);
Graph<Node, Edge> topo = this.topologyBWAware.get(bw);
Collection<Edge> edges = topo.getEdges();
Iterator<Edge> iterEdge;
Number i;
for(it
erEdge = edges.iterator(), i = 0;iterEdge.hasNext();){
Edge e = iterEdge.next();
edgeWeightMap.put(e,i);
i = i.intValue()+1;
}*/
clearMaxThroughput();
mtp =
null;
initMaxThroughput(null);
for (IListenRoutingUpdates ra : this.routingAware) {
try {
ra.recalculateDone();
} catch (Exception ex) {
log.error("
Exception on routingAware listener call", ex);
}
}
}
}
private void updateEdgeUtilization() {
log.debug("UpdateEdgeUtilization called");
clearMaxThroughput();
mtp = null;
init
MaxThroughput(null);
}
/**
* Function called by the dependency manager when all the required
36
* dependencies are satisfied
*
*/
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void init() {
log.debug("Rout
ing init() is called");
this.topologyBWAware = (ConcurrentMap<Short, Graph<Node, Edge>>) new ConcurrentHashMap();
this.sptBWAware = (ConcurrentMap<Short, DijkstraShortestPath<Node, Edge>>) new ConcurrentHashMap();
// Now create the 
default topology, which doesn't consider the
// BW, also create the corresponding Dijkstra calculation
Graph<Node, Edge> g = new SparseMultigraph();
Short sZero = Short.valueOf((short) 0);
this.topologyBWAware.put(sZero, g);
this.sptBWAware.put(sZero, new DijkstraShortestPath(g));
// Topologies for other BW will be added on a needed base
this.statMgr = new StatisticsManager();
this.lbRoutingTimer = new Timer();
this.lbRoutingTimerTask =
new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
updateEdgeUtilization();
}
};
}
/**
* Function called by the dependency manager when at least one dependency
* become unsati
sfied or when the component is shutting down because for
* example bundle is being stopped.
*
*/
void destroy() {
log.debug("Routing destroy() is called");
}
/**
* Function called by dependency manager after "init 
()" is called and after
* the services provided by the class are registered in the service registry
*
*/
void start() {
log.debug("Routing start() is called");
// build the routing database from the topology if it exists
.
Map<Edge, Set<Property>> edges = topologyManager.getEdges();
if (edges.isEmpty()) {
return;
}
List<TopoEdgeUpdate> topoedgeupdateList = new ArrayList<TopoEdgeUpdate>();
log.debug("Creating routing datab
ase from the topology");
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Edge, Set<Property>>> i = edges.entrySet()
.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
Map.Entry<Edge, Set<Property>> entry = i.next();
Edge e = entry.getKey();
Set<Property> props = entry.getValue();
TopoEdgeUpdate topoedgeupdate = new TopoEdgeUpdate(e, props,
UpdateType.ADDED);
topoedgeupdateList.add(topoedgeupdate);
37
}
edgeUpdate(topoedgeupdateL
ist);
// StatsTimer is set to 10s
lbRoutingTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(lbRoutingTimerTask, 0, 10000);
}
/**
* Function called by the dependency manager before the services exported by
* the component are unregistered, 
this will be followed by a "destroy ()"
* calls
*
*/
public void stop() {
log.debug("Routing stop() is called");
}
@Override
public void edgeOverUtilized(Edge edge) {
// TODO Auto
-
generated method stub
}
@Override
public void edgeUtilBackToNormal(Edge edge) {
// TODO Auto
-
generated method stub
}
public void setSwitchManager(ISwitchManager switchManager) {
this.switchManager = switchManager;
}
public void unsetS
witchManager(ISwitchManager switchManager) {
if (this.switchManager == switchManager) {
this.switchManager = null;
}
}
public void setReadService(IReadService readService) {
this.readService = readService;
}
public void unsetReadService(IReadService readService) {
if (this.readService == readService) {
this.readService = null;
}
}
public void setTopologyManager(ITopologyManager tm) {
this.topologyManager = tm;
}
public void unsetTopologyManager(ITopologyManager tm) {
if (this.topologyManager == tm) {
this.topologyManager = null;
}
}
}
```

Comment: What you have tried? Please add at least a snippet code.

Comment: Thanx for the reply sir, i have my pom.xml and loadbalncing.java file ready and i need to know where to run it on the controller

Comment: Please add them here, as snippet code. and explain more about opendaylight project.

Comment: Please check @Mr.hyde

Comment: Do i need eclipse IDE for this problem

Comment: @Mr.Hyde pleease revert back

Comment: @ChiragSharma -- Did you figure out the answer for the above?